# Iterate over a result set with an iterator ?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I got a result set "rs" from a database. rs contains only one column. I want to access the row at by its index and not all rows. Right now, i know that I can use this to iterate -

```
while(rs.next()){
   rs.getString("employee_name")
}
```

But, it does not let me select the row.

Actually, I want to take a row, add a comma to it and then add the next row. There is no comma after the last element. So, I will need to iterate up to second last or n-1 th row and keep on adding commas. After that, i only need to append the last row to my string and the job is done.

Comment: i wanted to know if we can iterate over a resultset like we iterate over an array. It may not make much sense here, but might be useful elsewhere.

Comment: Do you want to set comma in result set data, or what else ?

Comment: Why do you need to access a column by its index to make the number of rows of that column retrieved from a `resultSet` to be a comma separated string?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute(int) allows you to access a specific row in the `ResultSet` and there's methods such as `isLast()` that seem to be what you're looking for. Was there something confusing about the Javadoc you had a question about?

Answer (score -1):

Try the next:

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
while(rs.next()) {
    set.add(rs.getString("employee_name"));
}

Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(it.next());
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I think concat and append could be done within the first loop, so I will do things faster. The set is ok, but is unnecesary, because you discard it 2 lines below.

Answer (score -3):

```
String temp = "";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuiler();

while(rs.next()){    
   sb.append(rs.getString("employee_name"));
   sb.append(",");
}

temp = sb.toString();
temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length()-1);
```

Comment: PSR, you should read some Java before posting an answer like that. Initially has 3 bugs (now, after my comments you fixed it), and also you propose a bad solution.

Comment: If you like my answer please upvote. My answer works better than any other posted. Thanks!